# How to achieve jquery autocomplete without trigger from a character such as @ or #

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently I am able to trigger auto-complete using

```
options: {
  trigger: "@",
  allowDuplicates: true
},
```

I want when any letter in any word in the array is typed to cause autocomplete. I have tried to use an alphabet character e.g.

```
options: {
  trigger: "k",
  allowDuplicates: true
},
```

which is not working. 
Find [My Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq6MH/146/)

I want autocomplete every time one starts typing. I have tried other plug-ins and the problem is you can't tag more than 1 item.

Here is the documentation of the plugin: https://github.com/Hawkers/triggeredAutocomplete which is derived from jQueryUI autocomplete.

Comment: I guess the whole point is to use some special character to denote where the autocompletion should start. Something which is not part of a normal piece of prose. Otherwise it would be triggering constantly. How would the system know when you wanted to start an autocomplete and when you just wanted to type?

Comment: Or, maybe you should use the regular jQueryUI autocomplete plugin (or any other autocomplete plugin you choose), which will normally trigger when anything is typed, and not this derivation which actually calls itself "triggeredAutocomplete". Clearly its whole purpose is to trigger the autocomplete only on certain characters. It depends whether you want to make an autocomplete where the completed value is the only thing in the field, or whether you want it to be just one part of the text - if the latter, then you need some sort of trigger distinguishable from the rest of the text, hence @

Comment: @ADyson i want autocomplete every time one starts typing. I have tried other plug-ins and the problem is you cant tag more than 1 item

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple shows you a demo and code for selecting multiple items using the standard jQuery autocomplete. The widget you're using now is designed for a totally different use case.

Comment: @ADyson. Post it as the answer i will even accept it before trying because i am so sure it is what i need. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the regular jQueryUI autocomplete plugin (or any other autocomplete plugin you choose), which will normally trigger when anything is typed, and not this derivation which actually calls itself "triggeredAutocomplete". and whose entire purpose is to trigger the autocomplete only on certain characters, so that other text can be entered into the textbox as well without constantly triggering an autocomplete query.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple shows you a demo and code for selecting multiple items using the standard jQueryUI autocomplete.

The widget you're using now is designed for a totally different use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regular jQueryUI autocomplete.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/